# Get Database value into array

Tags: php

I'm trying to fix following code .

```
 $q3=$this->db->query("SELECT COALESCE(SUM(b.sales_qty),0) AS sales_qty, a.item_name FROM db_items AS a, db_salesitems AS b ,db_sales AS c WHERE a.id=b.`item_id` AND b.sales_id=c.`id` AND c.`sales_status`='Final' AND c.`delivery_status`='Deliverd' GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY sales_qty DESC limit 10");
        if($q3->num_rows() >0){
          foreach($q3->result() as $res3){
              //extract($res3);
              if($res3->sales_qty>0){
                //echo "(label "=>.$res3->item_name. ,"y"=> .$res3->sales_qty. "),";
                echo $dataPoints [] = "array('label'  => '".$res3->item_name."', 'y' =>'".$res3->sales_qty."'),";//var_dump($dataPoints);
                // echo $dataPoints;
          
              }
          }
         
        }
```

I want to get that database value into array in following method. but trying to different way can't find the answer .

```
$dataPoints = array(
array("label"=> "Food + Drinks", "y"=> 590),
array("label"=> "Activities and Entertainments", "y"=> 261),
array("label"=> "Health and Fitness", "y"=> 158),
array("label"=> "Shopping & Misc", "y"=> 72),
array("label"=> "Transportation", "y"=> 191),
array("label"=> "Rent", "y"=> 573),
array("label"=> "Travel Insurance", "y"=> 126)
  
);
```

Comment: For one .. Remove the `echo`  --  You cannot echo an array .. `echo $dataPoints []`  After your loop .. `print_r(dataPoints )`

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the library you're using for the database, and that the query actually works.  But if you alias both columns with what you want them to be in the array, like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(b.sales_qty),0) AS y, a.item_name AS label
```

Then just this:

```
$dataPoints[] = (array)$res3;
```

If you can get an array, like in CodeIgniter using the `array` argument or `getResultArray()`, then just this:

```
while($dataPoints[] = $q3->result('array'));
```